# How to modify Input::all() data in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I use Laravel 4 and my store function in controller is :

```
public function store()
{
    $validation = new Services\Validators\Speaker;

    if($validation->passes())
    {                   

        $file = Input::file('image');

        $imageName  = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move('photos/',$imageName);

        $input = Input::all();          

        $speaker = $this->speaker->create(Input::all());


        return Redirect::route('speaker.index');
    }
```

The uploaded photo is moved to the specified place and named correctly. But in the database, the image file name is not correctly saved. "C:\xampp\tmp\php2B7D.tmp" this kind of data is saved. I want to save image name and path. Any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should make change in $input ,and ->create($input).

Comment: yes,I would. I repeated Input::all(). thanks

Comment: I found the answer. Instead of $input = Input::all(), I replace with $input = array('datafield1'=>'datavalue1', 'datafield2'=>'datavalue2);

Comment: after all $input =  Input::all() is a lazy way, if it's fine that you know what's Input::all() return. otherwise  $input = array('datafield1'=>Input::get("field")) will be more safer.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. here the code

```
    public function store()
{
    $validation = new Services\Validators\Speaker;

    if($validation->passes())
    {

        $file = Input::file('image');

        $imageName  = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();


        $file->move('photos/',$imageName);

        $input = array('name'=>Input::get('name'),
                        'image'=> 'photos/'.$imageName,
                        'desc'=>Input::get('desc')
                    );



        $speaker = $this->speaker->create($input);

        return Redirect::route('speaker.index');
    }
```